# Dojo widgetsintemplatemixin doesn't parse data-dojo-props

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

My template is

```
    <div>
    <div class="header" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'>
        <span class="leftHeaderContent">
        ${leftButton}
        <div class="headerText">${currentView}</div>
        </span>
        <span class="rightHeaderContent">
        <div data-dojo-attach-event='onclick: clickProfile' class='profileButton'><div class=profileButtonInner></div></div>
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I use _WidgetsInTemplateMixin to parse this trough a custom widget. Everything works, except that the 'fixed:"top"' property of the heading doesn't work.

I have a scrollable view and the heading scrolls with the content.

I learned that _WidgetsInTemplateMixin doesn't work if the root element of the template is a widget, so I put the  elements around it. It parses it as a heading widget, except the properties.

Can someone help me?

Comment: **How** do you know it is not parsing `data-dojo-props`? Did you check with a debugger? If it's already handling `data-dojo-type`, then it seems far more likely that there's some widget-relationship/layout/CSS quirk at play instead.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a [ScrollableView](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView.html#id6) to keep the header fixed at the top. According to the documentation, place the `Header` on the **outside** of your `ScrollableView`, as in their example:

```
<h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'>Application Header Bar</h1>
<div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView">
    ....
</div>
<div id="view2" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView">
    ....
</div>
<h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"bottom"'>Application Footer Bar</h1>
```

**Results**: (Even though they don't show it, the content is scrollable, and the header and footer are both fixed.)

[image]

Comment: the view is a ScrollableView and you only have to put the header outside of your ScrollableView if you want it global for you application (/page).

Answer (score 0):

Try change `data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'` to `data-dojo-props="fixed:'top'"`.

If it wont help, u could set that property into `"postCreate"` method. (or `startup`, I am not sure which one will be correct, I used **1.6 Dojo**.)

Comment: The change didn't work, but how can I add the property in the postCreate? How can I find the headingwidget from the template?

Comment: U should used `data-dojo-attach-point` property, it will create property available in context of widget, via which u will be able to get all methods of sub-widget.